# How to write programmatically into DataGridViewComboBoxCell?

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcomboboxcell

I'm trying to write programmatically into DataGridViewComboBoxCell but I can't do that.
I tried:

```
datagrid.rows[index].cell[1].value = "myvalue";
```

But this did not work.

Comment: Are you trying to update the drop down list or the text box in the DataGridViewComboBoxCell ?

Comment: update the  text box in the DataGridViewComboBoxCell from code